Getting "`&'a T` is not an iterator" when setting trait bound `for <'a> &'a Self: IntoIterator`
I am trying to define a trait Foo with a Higher-Rank Trait Bound on the &'a Self type of IntoIterator. In other words, I would like to require the implementing type T to be iterable by immutable borrow (i.e. such that &T: IntoIterator).
I also want a function bar that takes an argument of type T: Foo. But this gives me an error.
Here is the MRE: (playground on nightly 1.79)
trait Foo
where for<'a> &'a Self: IntoIterator
{}

fn bar<T: Foo>(_: T) {}

This is the error:
error[E0277]: `&'a T` is not an iterator
 --> src/lib.rs:5:11
  |
5 | fn bar<T: Foo>(_: T) {}
  |           ^^^ `&'a T` is not an iterator
  |
  = help: the trait `for<'a> Iterator` is not implemented for `&'a T`, which is required by `for<'a> &'a T: IntoIterator`
  = help: the trait `Iterator` is implemented for `&mut I`
  = note: required for `&'a T` to implement `for<'a> IntoIterator`
note: required by a bound in `Foo`
 --> src/lib.rs:2:25
  |
1 | trait Foo
  |       --- required by a bound in this trait
2 | where for<'a> &'a Self: IntoIterator
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Foo`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.

I don't understand the error. Why would I have to implement for<'a> Iterator for &'a T? The Iterator trait does not seem to be a super-trait of IntoIterator.
Also, why does it tell me that it is "required for &'a T to implement for<'a> IntoIterator". After all, that is exactly the trait bound I defined for Foo, which is the bound I set for the type of the bar parameter, isn't it?
I feel like I am missing something fundamental here, but this is one of those rare cases, when I don't find the compiler's error message helpful at all.
PS:
This sentence adds even more confusion: "the trait Iterator is implemented for &mut I". What on earth is I now?

Let's look at a classic supertrait:
trait Foo: IntoIterator {}

fn bar<T: Foo>() {}

For bar to compile, T must be well-formed (something like "able to exist"). Because T requires Foo, and Foo requires IntoIterator, that means we must prove T: IntoIterator.
Without special support from the compiler, we would fail to prove it. bar() does not list T: IntoIterator as a bound, so we cannot prove that T: IntoIterator.
But for us to not need to write T: IntoIterator every time we use Foo, the compiler helps us. It elaborates the Foo: IntoIterator bound, i.e. make it implied. If we have a T: Foo bound, it implies we also have a T: IntoIterator bound. Now we can trivially fulfill the requirement T: IntoIterator.
But the truth is, the compiler doesn't always elaborate bounds from traits. It only does so for supertraits, i.e. bounds of the form trait Trait: Supertrait or trait Trait where Self: Supertrait (Since the former is essentially a syntax sugar for the later).
Your bound isn't a supertrait bound, as it's a bound on for<'a> &'a Self, not on Self. As such, the compiler doesn't elaborate it. But the requirement for well-formedness is still there - it just that you must spell it explicitly:
fn bar<T: Foo>(_: T)
where
    for<'a> &'a T: IntoIterator,
{
}

Playground.

An aside about the error message:
The compiler is over-smart here. It tries to proves T: IntoIterator, and it sees there is a blanket impl impl<I: Iterator> IntoIterator for I. So it told you you are missing an Iterator impl, when you're really missing an IntoIterator impl. I've read a suggestion to change this, but I can't find it now.
The paragraph help: the trait `Iterator` is implemented for `&mut I`  is indeed confusing. The compiler regularly lists the existing impl (because perhaps you thought you should match one), and I believe in this case it lists only this one is because it believes you might have confused &T with &mut T, i.e. you thought there is an Iterator impl for &T (which would match your bounds) but in fact there is one for &mut T. Now, even if you would require &mut T this still wouldn't solve the problem, as this impl also requires the referent to be Iterator, but the compiler doesn't analyze to this depth.

Thank you for this very clear answer. If you don't mind a follow-up: I understand now that the compiler does not do this, but wouldn't it be feasible for it to also be able to elaborate the bound on the borrowed type? This doesn't feel like such a stretch, since Self and &'a Self are so intimately related. In other words, I would expect the &'a Self-bounds to be implied as well, any time I require the trait itself as a bound. This seems like it would make a reasonable feature request. Or do you see any significant obstacles?

@DaniilFajnberg It doesn't currently. If you want it to do, you can open an issue. But consider that it might be blocked on the wish not to make a handful of exceptions. Elaboration of bounds of Self and not others is already quite surprising (as you saw), if we will add other (arbitrarily chosen) types it will be even more so. So people may want "all-or-nothing".

I respectfully disagree. I don't find the elaboration of Self bounds surprising at all. It feels totally natural for trait bounds to be transitive. If I define that something that can Run must always also be able to Walk, I naturally expect that if a function takes something with the ability to to Run, that thing will also have the ability to Walk, without having to spell that out again. It is literally logically implied. As for other kinds of elaboration, I guess I don't have enough experience to see many other reasonable possibilities aside from the borrowed Self types.

In any case, thank you for the insight. I think it is worth a shot to throw this out there as a feature request.

@DaniilFajnberg I mean that it is surprising it elaborates only them.

Right, my mistake, I misread your comment.
